# Refit: Is there a way to send a list of complex object in query

Tags: c#, refit

Trying to send request using Refit to controller:

```
[HttpGet("api/users/{userId}/appointments")]
public async Task Get(Guid userId, [FromQuery] FilterRow[] filters = null) {}
```

Added interface with this method:

```
[Get("/api/users/{userId}/appointments")]
Task<IEnumerable> Get([AliasAs("userId")] Guid userId, [AliasAs("filters")] FilterRow[] filters);
```

FilterRow:

```
public class FilterRow
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string FilterValue { get; set; }
    public FilterCondition FilterCondition { get; set; }
}

public enum FilterCondition
{
    Equals = 0,
    LessThan = 1,
    LessThanOrEqual = 2,
    GreaterThan = 3,
    GreaterThanOrEqual = 4,
    NotEquals = 5
}
```

Tried to add RefitUrlParameterFormatter. But to it's function Format comes separate values from this object. Solved this using IFormattable to this object, but even with this it didn't work correctly (Controller didn't get any values)

Answer (score 0):

Refit supports sending collections as query string parameters.

Use the Query attribute to specify format in which collections should be formatted in query string

```
[Get("/users/list")]
Task Search([Query(CollectionFormat.Multi)]int[] ages);

Search(new [] {10, 20, 30})
>>> "/users/list?ages=10&ages=20&ages=30"

[Get("/users/list")]
Task Search([Query(CollectionFormat.Csv)]int[] ages);

Search(new [] {10, 20, 30})
>>> "/users/list?ages=10%2C20%2C30"
```

You can also specify collection format in RefitSettings, that will be used by default, unless explicitly defined in Query attribute.

```
var gitHubApi = RestService.For<IGitHubApi>("https://api.github.com",
new RefitSettings {
    CollectionFormat = CollectionFormat.Multi
});
```

[Link to docs](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit#collections-as-querystring-parameters)

Please be aware of sending a list of complex objects as query string parameters. This can be a smell of improper API design